# Chances of someone finding your lost phone and/or authentication device and having the same fingerprint

Tags: probability

I was going through the [FAQ page](http://fidoalliance.org/about/faq/) of the [FIDO alliance](http://fidoalliance.org/), a consortium to implement a next generation authentication system. To answer to the question,

> How secure are fingerprints?

They have said,

> The possibility of someone having the same fingerprint as you is about
>   1 in 6 million. The chances of someone finding your lost phone and/or
>   authentication device AND having the same fingerprint is greater than
>   1 in a million. ...

It doesn't make sense to me. Shouldn't the later probability be smaller?

Comment: Yes, this looks like it's just a small typo.

Comment: And unless you believe in some weird kind of synchronicity theory I would even go so far as to say that the chance is smaller than 1 in 6 million.

Comment: Maybe the "m" in "greater than 1 in a million" was intended to be a "b"?